# Watch for changes in a queue containing struct

Tags: go

I have two goroutines:

1. first one adds task to queue
2. second cleans up from the queue based on status

**Add and cleanup might not be simultaneous.**

If the status of task is success, I want to delete the task from the queue, if not, I will retry for status to be success (will have time limit). If that fails, I will log and delete from queue.

We can't communicate between add and delete because that is not how the real world scenario works.

I want something like a watcher which monitors addition in queue and does the following cleanup. To increase complexity, Add might be adding even during cleanup is happening (not shown here). I want to implement it without using external packages.

How can I achieve this?

```
type Task struct {
    name   string
    status string //completed, failed
}

var list []*Task

func main() {
    done := make(chan bool)
    go Add()
    time.Sleep(15)
    go clean(done)
    <-done
}

func Add() {
    t1 := &Task{"test1", "completed"}
    t2 := &Task{"test2", "failed"}
    list = append(list, t1, t2)
}

func clean() {
    for k, v := range list {
        if v.status == "completed" {
            RemoveIndex(list, k)
        } else {
            //for now consider this as retry
            v.status == "completed"
        }
        if len(list) > 0 {
            clean()
        }
        <-done
    }
}

func RemoveIndex(s []int, index int) []int {
    return append(s[:index], s[index+1:]...)
}
```

Comment: Not a GoLang dev but your issue may be more a design complexity.

Seems to achieve your goal you may want to have your tasks struct to have knowledge of the task queue.

type Task struct {
    name   string
    status string //completed, failed
    list []*Task
}

If there is a possibility of more tasks-lists, ( task could be added to) might make sense,
Then the task itself could broadcast its completion to the list to be remove (or even remove itself).
Memory-performance impact of Tasks struct having list info may be depend on goLang

Comment: i.e. https://flaviocopes.com/golang-event-listeners/
Not sure if this would apply to your scenario.

Comment: To keep track of gorutines. I see that you are using channels. then I would recommend using either sync.mutex or sync.waitGroup the first one will lock untill your first is ready and pass the result to the second one only if ready. the waitgroup one will only make sure that each one executes. So I would recommend sync.mutex happy new year.

Comment: as long as you want to use multiple routines to manage your slice, you will have to use a synchronization mechanism, sync.Mutex or similar. I dont understand the upvotes because clearly your problem description can not take advantage of the languages primitives, it can only synchronize access through mutexes.

Comment: @BrendanB thankyou, was not exactly  what i was looking but go my solution

Comment: @mh-cbon, mutex i'd use to lock the array before addition or before deletion. if you don't have a solution does not mean you can downvote and mock the language itself

Comment: @sai I said that as long as you want to have multiple routines working on a shared variables, then there is **no** other solutions than mutexes (or disguised channel). period. Your solution is just bad, because it does not have clear exit conditions, it behaves unpredictably. Because your "real wolrd scenario", aka the bad situation you are dealing with, is justifying, to you, to keep doing bad programming. One solution, that involves maintaining a slice of task might just be https://play.golang.org/p/2vFIfArXBGK but 1/ to me there is just too much to explain so that i make it an answer ...

Comment: ...2/ other (simpler, thus probably better) solutions exists but they dont maitain a slice of tasks, and they have drawbacks, which once again i dont feel like i want spent time to explain. 3/ none of those solutions attempt to watch and monitor or whatever else funky

Answer (score 1):

so i found a solution which works for me and posting it here for anyone it might be helpful for.

in my main i have added a ticker which runs every x seconds to watch if something is added in the queue.

```
type Task struct {
    name   string
    status string //completed, failed
}

var list []*Task

func main() {
    done := make(chan bool)
c := make(chan os.Signal, 2)
    go Add()
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            // case <-done:
            //  Cleaner(k)
            case <-ticker.C:
                Monitor(done)
            }
        }
    }()
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
    <-c
    //waiting for interrupt here

}

func Add() {
    t1 := &Task{"test1", "completed"}
    t2 := &Task{"test2", "failed"}
    list = append(list, t1, t2)
}

func Monitor(done chan bool) {
    if len(list) > 0 {
        Cleaner()
    }
}

func cleaner(){
  //do cleaning here
 // pop each element from queue and delete
}

func RemoveIndex(s []int, index int) []int {
    return append(s[:index], s[index+1:]...)
}
```

so now this solution does not need to depend on communication between go routines,
in a real world scenario, the programme never dies and keeps adding and cleaning based on use case.you can optimize better by locking and unlocking before addition to queue and deletion from queue.